# How to output collection items to a column in a new worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code intended to extract unique values from a range, whose output is printed in the debug window:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim uniques As Collection
    Dim source As Range

    Set source = ActiveSheet.Range("P2:AF60000")
    Set uniques = GetUniqueValues(source.Value)

    Dim it
    For Each it In uniques
        Debug.Print it
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetUniqueValues(ByVal values As Variant) As Collection
    Dim result As Collection
    Dim cellValue As Variant
    Dim cellValueTrimmed As String

    Set result = New Collection
    Set GetUniqueValues = result

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each cellValue In values
        cellValueTrimmed = Trim(cellValue)
        If cellValueTrimmed = "" Then GoTo NextValue
        result.Add cellValueTrimmed, cellValueTrimmed
    NextValue:
    Next cellValue

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

How I could print it to a column (a value per cell) in a new sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new sheet with the name you prefer, and then iterate the cells of one column to add the values to it. Here's one way to create a sheet using a helper function:

```
Public Function CreateSheet(ByVal shtName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = shtName
    End With
    Set CreateSheet = ws
End Function
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Sub main()
    Dim uniques As Collection
    Dim source As Range

    Set source = ActiveSheet.Range("P2:AF60000")
    Set uniques = GetUniqueValues(source.Value)

    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Set outputSheet = CreateSheet("Output")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To uniques.Count
        'Debug.Print uniques(i)
        outputSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = uniques(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

This will create a new sheet with the name `Output` and populate column `A` of that sheet with the values from your `uniques` collection.